# Creating a window doesn't work but gives no error messages

Tags: c++, window

I'm trying to create a window, none appear but I don't get an error message anywhere except for the one I put in testing hWnd.

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>

#include "entity.h"

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(message)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message,wParam,lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc= (WNDPROC)WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra= 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra= 0;
    wcex.hInstance= hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon= 0;
    wcex.hCursor= LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground= (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName= 0;
    wcex.lpszClassName= "Extt";
    wcex.hIconSm= 0;

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "FAILED TO REGISTER WINDOW CLASS", "ERROR", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow("WinD", "Chair", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 480, 480, 480, 480, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if (hWnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "FAILED TO CREATE WINDOW", "ERROR", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

I just don't know what to do anymore.

I did everything like the guy said, I've read and re-read the page several times and can not understand why this won't work.

Comment: Use [`GetLastError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the error code from the last failed system call. See [a list of system error codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) what it is, or use [`FormatMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get a string.

Comment: ok, it says it was an error ""Cannot find Window class"". so I named both windows classes the same and now it works. thanks. there's literally always something i miss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your classname parameters do not match. If you had used `GetLastError()` it would have returned 1407, which is:

```
ERROR_CANNOT_FIND_WND_CLASS
    1407 (0x57F)
    Cannot find window class.
```

Either change `wcex.lpszClassName = "Extt";` to `wcex.lpszClassName = "WinD";` or change the first parameter to `CreateWindow` to `"Extt"`.